# Is it possible to directly parse API protobuf files in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, protocol-buffers

I am making an app that shows the real-time location of local buses. I have an API that returns the `.pb (protobuf)` file with Vehicle Positions. I am handling `proto buffers` for the first time and I have no idea why we can't parse them like `JSON` file.

I saw a library named `"Swift-Protobuf"`, but in its documentation. They are asking to run a command to convert `protobuf` file into a swift object. But as I am making API calls every minute that returns the `protobuf` file. How can I run that command every time?

```
$ protoc --swift_out=. my.proto
```

I just want to parse those `.pb` files into a swift object. So that I can use the data on my project.

Comment: You could take a look at the [Process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process) class for running your command

Answer (score 2):

> They are asking to run a command to convert protobuf file into a swift object. But as I am making API calls every minute that returns the protobuf file. How can I run that command every time?

I think you've misunderstood the documentation: you don't need to run `protoc --swift_out=. my.proto` for every .pb file you receive; you use that command to generate code that knows how to read and write data according to the schema that you define in a .proto file. You can then take that generated code and add it to your iOS project, and after that you can use the code to read and write protobuf data that matches your schema.

> I am making an app that shows the real-time location of local buses.

So before you can get started, you're going to need a .proto file that describes the data format used by whoever provides the bus location data, *or* you'll need whoever provides that data to use SwiftProtobuf or similar to generate a Swift parser for their .proto file.

> ...I have no idea why we can't parse them like JSON file.

Well, the point of the protobuf format is to be language-agnostic and faster/easier to use than JSON or XML, and one of the design decisions that Google apparently made is to sacrifice human readability for size/speed. So you *could* write a parser to parse these files just as you would JSON data, but you'd have to learn how the format works. But it's a lot easier to describe the data you're sending and have a program generate the code. One nice aspect of this arrangement is that you can describe the schema once and then generate code that works with that schema for several languages, so you don't have to write code separately for your iOS app, your Android app, and your server.